# Listen for Google Analytics hit using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am using Google Tag Manager and want to fire a tag when a hardcoded pageview hit is sent to Google Analytics.

Is it possible to listen for hits being sent to Google Analytics using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that some code is executed when GA sends it's data you can use [tasks](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/tasks) in GA - specifically the custom task, which does nothing by default and is there so you can add custom behaviour to GA.

A task is a javascript callback that performs certain actions during a tracking call (checking if there is a cookie, setting the page speed sample, checking if the payload data is correct etc.).Google introduced the custom task as a custom callback basically for scenarios like yours.

Very much from the top of my hat this would look something like this:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('set', 'customTask', function(model) {
  page = model.get('page');
  if(page.indexOf('pageview/where/i/want/my/pixel') {
     trackingUrl  =  "/path/to/pixel";
     trackingPixel = new Image();
     trackingPixel.src= trackingUrl;
  }
});
```

(untested, might need tweaking).

But the idea is that a task is only executed when GA sends a tracking call, so if you want to tie your tag to the GA call that's the way to go.